# Painting a cell in Stage

Tags: simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

My robot has to traverse from one point to another using the Stage simulator. I would like to paint the start and end cell but I don't know which message I have to send on which topic.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57518/painting-a-cell-in-stage/) by [EdwardD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4276/edwardd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you need to change the Start and End point during the runtime? If not you can create a way-point mark ( none obstacle ) for it to show the start and end point.

---

Originally posted by [bombilee](https://answers.ros.org/users/4584/bombilee/) with karma: 86 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0